# Converting Object to Class object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

in my Spring MVC project i m using Hibernate, by using Criteria API i am applying Group BY and Order BY clause. Query get executed on DB successfully and it brings result also but its an array of Object--

Here is code of Criteria API

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DashboardSubindicatorSubmission.class, "DashboardSubindicatorSubmission")
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.sum("InputValue").as("InputValue"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("fkAccademicYearId"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("fkAssessmentPlanID"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("fkSubindicatorID"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("InputTitle")))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("fkAccademicYearId"))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("fkAssessmentPlanID"))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("InputTitle"));
        List<DashboardSubindicatorSubmission> dashboardSubindicatorSubmissionList = (List<DashboardSubindicatorSubmission>)criteria.list();
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        return dashboardSubindicatorSubmissionList;
```

I am casting `criteria.list()` to `List<DashboardSubindicatorSubmission>` but when i try to do `dashboardSubindicatorSubmissionList.get(i)` on controller it gives me exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to mkcl.accreditation.model.DashboardSubindicatorSubmission`.

i come to know that, though i m casting it to `List<DashboardSubindicatorSubmission>` still its an list of `object[]` thats why i cant do `dashboardSubindicatorSubmissionList.get(i)` because it returns me object of `DashboardSubindicatorSubmission`. **(Correct me if i am wrong)**

So how can i convert my result into list of `DashboardSubindicatorSubmission` class?
Does setResultTransformer() helps me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. When you use projections, Hibernate doesn't know how to respect each field because it uses the name of each field to build objects and he doesn't know the names yet.

Thus, your first option is to name the fields grouped so that they match the names of object properties. This is necessary even if the string you use in projection is already the name of the object field. Something like:

```
.add(Projections.groupProperty("fkAccademicYearId"), "fkAccademicYearId") // same value
.add(Projections.groupProperty("fkAssessmentPlanID"), "other") // other value
```

The second option is to do what you yourself suggested, create your own implementation of ResultTransformer. I reckon this a interesting option if you want to extract other object of this query, as when you make a report.